# Micro services Data Validation from Other services data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have a micro services question hoping someone can provide some guidance.
I have a service which returns a list of valid car makes and models from a database and a separate service which allows me to perform CRUD operations to create, update, delete car listings for sale.

When creating a new car listing how can i validate the POST request for a method to create a new listing from the data that is present as part of the other service. e.g. when adding a new listing i want to validate if the make and model are valid or not. but that information is present in the other service.

Comment: two ways you can do 1) call microservice for data and validate the data in your microservice 2)Communicate through event/queue system.

Answer (score 1):

It's a straightforward approach and normal pattern in Microservices architecture. If your service B needs any data(or validation in your case) which is owned by Service A, then definitely it needs to contact service A.

You can have multiple ways for communicating with other systems eg, Rest or gRPC etc.

In addition to this, you can also replicate/cache those data at the service B side if you think calling every time service A is an overhead for service B.

But remember these are high-level ideas about how you need to approach this problem. You can derive a better solution from the above-suggested patterns.